# How to implement update handler for Primefaces progressBar?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a regular Ajax PF progressBar:

```
        <p:progressBar value="#{myTask.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" ajax="true" widgetVar="progress">
            <p:ajax event="complete" oncomplete="progress.cancel();"></p:ajax>
        </p:progressBar>
```

How can I run my JavaScript code whenever progressBar has updated it's value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`RequestContext`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml) object to execute javascript from the server side. To use this:

1. Define a method in your backing bean, in which you'll make use of the `RequestContext` object

   ```
   public void doJs() {
       RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
       context.execute("progress.cancel();");
   }
   ```
2. Set this method in the `listener` attribute of the `<p:ajax/>`

   ```
   <p:progressBar value="#{myTask.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" ajax="true"
       widgetVar="progress">
       <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{theBean.doJs}"/>
   </p:progressBar>
   ```

EDIT: To perform the execute after every ajax update, the setup is a little different:

1. Add the `interval` attribute to your progress bar to introduce a better controlled polling mechanism

   ```
   <p:progressBar value="#{myTask.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" ajax="true"
       widgetVar="progress" interval="3000">
   ```
2. Add an `<f:event/>` to hook into the page lifecycle of the component and perform your server-side update from there. I'm going to recommend the `PostValidateEvent` event

   ```
   <p:progressBar value="#{myTask.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" ajax="true"
       widgetVar="progress" interval="3000">
       <f:event type="postValidate" listener="#{theBean.doJs}" />
   </p:progressBar>
   ```

Comment: You probably mean adding execute() call in myTask.progress getter since I need to execute JS after every progress bar update, not when its completed?

Comment: Proper syntax is <f:event listener="#{myTask.doJS}" type="postValidate"/> but it works now. While I dont like putting any JS code on backend this seems like the only workable solution. Thanks!

Comment: @rootkit, thanks, oversight on my part. Kinda typed that in a hurry